# scrapy xpath return empty list while response is not empty

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape information from 2 tables on the [website](http://www.sc.edu/about/directory/?name=zhao)

I firstly scrape the tables. It turns out that staffs and students are empty while response is not empty. I also find the table tab in page source. Can anyone find out what's the problem?

```
import scrapy
from universities.items import UniversitiesItem


class UniversityOfSouthCarolinaColumbia(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'uscc'
    allowed_domains = ['sc.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://www.sc.edu/about/directory/?name=']

    def parse(self, response):    
        for ln in ['Zhao']:
            query = response.url + ln
            yield scrapy.Request(query, callback=self.parse_item)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_item(response):
        staffs = response.xpath('//table[@id="directorystaff"]/tbody/tr[@role="row"]')
        students = response.xpath('//table[@id="directorystudent"]/tbody/tr[@role="row"]')

        print('--------------------------')
        print('staffs', staffs)
        print('==========================')
        print('students', students)
```

Comment: Why you declare `parse_item` as `@staticmethod`?

Comment: I don't understand either. This is an auto fix by pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's realy cool question. I'm investigate this. And I has concluded that the response does not contain info about the tags attribute. I think that browser is modify page_source_body with anybody script adding attribute to tags.

In response tr-tags do not have attribute 'role'

Please see it:

```
             <table class="display" id="directorystaff" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: left">Name</th>
                  <th style="text-align: left">Email</th>
                  <th style="text-align: left">Phone</th>
                  <th style="text-align: left">Department</th>
                  <th style="text-align: left">Office Address</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>  
              <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left">Zhao, Xia  &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">(803) 777-8436&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">Chemistry&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">537&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left">Zhao, Xing  &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">Mechanical Engineering&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
```

[image: It response on request query]

In this picture we see the response page
[image]

and in this picture we see page on browser:
[image]

So, if you want got list of staffs , I'm recommend next XPath:

`//table[@id="directorystaff"]/tbody/tr/td`

[image]

And for students, I'm recommend next XPath:

`//table[@id="directorystudent"]/tbody/tr/td`

If you want something else, you can modify this is XPath query.

This is example for you:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
x = requests.get("https://www.sc.edu/about/directory/?name=Zhao")
ht = html.fromstring(x.text)
element = ht.xpath('//table[@id="directorystaff"]/tbody/tr/td')
for el in element:
    print(el.text)
```

And output:

```
>>Zhao, Xia   
>> 
>>(803) 777-8436 
>>Chemistry 
>>537 
>>Zhao, Xing   
>> 
>> 
>>Mechanical Engineering
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that there is no "role" under "tr". So page source is a different thing from what we see in inspect?

Comment: In general, it is different. Page source is what you download (content generated on server) and what Scrapy sees. However, there can frontend technologies (JavaScript etc.) take place after the download and during rendering, which set some content dynamically during page rendering in browser. That's what you see in inspect.